# The easiest way to approach puzzle menu in web design

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I have 2 basic ideas how to execute my designing, my question is which is better will give me more freedom with animations fiddling in CSS and so on later on.

[image]

That would be a navigation menu and hovering over one of them would make it bigger.

---

2 ideas:

1. CSS clip-path: polygon tool. The problem with this thing is support on IE and older Firefox
2. Just create this 'puzzle' piece in Illustrator. It probably would be harder to fiddle in CSS with this thing. Each piece would have to be in different colour so I would have to create a lot of images.

---

PS. I'll appreciate any other tips/hints when it comes to executing something like that

Comment: If these are right angles, it may be possible to fake it with [CSS triangles](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/) made with border: [generator](http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/). 1 for the arrow, 2 for the tail for example, with :after, :before and an empty extra element if necessary. Doesn't need to be right angles in fact, but it'll be harder to get the precise width and height... Compatibility IE8+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using [CSS transforms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transforms). You could use the [`before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) and [`after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) pseudo-elements with the skew transform to achieve this shape, without the need for clipping paths, images, or vector graphics.

## Working Example:

```css
ul,
li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

ul {
    margin: 50px;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    width: 75px;
    height: 125px;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:before,
li a:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background: grey;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    border: 1px solid black;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}
li a:before {
    left: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    -webkit-transform: skewY(-45deg);
       -moz-transform: skewY(-45deg);
        -ms-transform: skewY(-45deg);
         -o-transform: skewY(-45deg);
            transform: skewY(-45deg);
}
li a:after {
    right: 0;
    border-left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: skewY(45deg);
       -moz-transform: skewY(45deg);
        -ms-transform: skewY(45deg);
         -o-transform: skewY(45deg);
            transform: skewY(45deg);
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">text1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">text2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">text3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

A good approach would be using `SVG` 's for this. You can create only one in Illustrator, and then change its size, color and other via CSS.

I recommand using inline `SVG` (instead of importing it like a regular image), since it gives you a lot of control on the individual components - so that they can be easily animated.

The browser support is [pretty good](http://caniuse.com/#search=svg).

Here's a good guide to get started with SVG's : 
https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/